# Apple Thunderbolt disconnecting, reconnecting from MBP 2018

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, error, thunderbolt-display

I have a 2018 Macbook Pro with a Thunderbolt display hooked up as an external monitor using the Apple TB2/MDP to TB3 adapter.

I have had this machine in to Apple to try to figure out why it is constantly disconnecting, losing all peripheral connection, mostly reconnecting but sometimes just requiring me to yank the cable from the laptop and plugging it back in, after which it goes back to normal but sometimes for an hour or two, sometimes for five minutes before it goes all over again.

I've monitored the Console religiously and have the same error pattern that appears tons of times at once (see below).

It's been to Apple (I have apple care) twice now, neither time being fixed, the second time they just said "nothing is wrong" after having it for a week and asking me to explain in further detail via email what was wrong.

Here is what I've tried doing to troubleshoot:

- NVRAM/SMC reset about a hundred times or so
- A new Apple TB2-TB3 adapter
- Disconnect all peripherals Re-install OS (latest Catalina
  build)
- Erase & install new user and rebuild entire system
- Removed any display modifying tools like F.lux, Magnet
- Turned off discrete graphics option in power saver (and turned it back on again)
- Tried different power adapters

**I also bought a refurb 2019 MBP from Apple and returned it to test, and tested it out and same thing happens. Leading me to believe it's the monitor itself or the adapter cannot handle the data**

I realize that it really could be the monitor here that is the issue (or something in an app I use), but I can't for the life of me find ANYONE with this issue on the Community at apple.com or elsewhere. Searches lead me down a rabbit hole of other issues and here I am. I'd like to not have to buy a new monitor, my TB display is an amazing monitor for my needs.

Any advice would be most appreciated, and the error code snippet is below. TIA!

```
error   15:47:00.903348-0600    Console enable_updates_common timed out waiting for updates to reenable
error   15:47:00.915566-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:00.915787-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:00.917778-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:00.918001-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:00.919198-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:00.925802-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:00.925837-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:00.929445-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:00.929645-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:00.931564-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:00.931771-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:00.932931-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:00.933222-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:01.064721-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.064924-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.066911-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.067123-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.068310-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.068594-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:01.079555-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.079762-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.081794-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.082007-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.082989-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.083265-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:01.094193-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.094398-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.096370-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.096585-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.097719-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.100555-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.100735-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.102507-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.102690-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.103604-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.106460-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.106628-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.108294-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.108475-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.108974-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.112258-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.112445-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.114299-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.114497-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.115268-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.116242-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:01.116261-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:01.116283-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:01.120388-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.120604-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.122668-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.122870-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.123905-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.124835-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:01.124856-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:01.124908-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:01.128561-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.128746-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.130436-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.130630-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.131674-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:01.132519-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - ColorSyncUtilsUpdateDisplayProfiles: NULL device for (displayID = 0x042496d9, "Thunderbolt Display Calibrated 2"): skipped
error   15:47:01.133639-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - ColorSyncUtilsUpdateDisplayProfiles: NULL device for (displayID = 0x042496d9, "Thunderbolt Display Calibrated 2"): skipped
error   15:47:01.134790-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - ColorSyncUtilsUpdateDisplayProfiles: NULL device for (displayID = 0x042496d9, "Thunderbolt Display Calibrated 2"): skipped
error   15:47:01.500762-0600    Music   enable_updates_common timed out waiting for updates to reenable
error   15:47:01.952054-0600    com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent   Invalid display 0x042496d9
error   15:47:02.323276-0600    Console enable_updates_common timed out waiting for updates to reenable
error   15:47:02.493704-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.493925-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.496126-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.496368-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.497987-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.504693-0600    Music   enable_updates_common timed out waiting for updates to reenable
error   15:47:02.515841-0600    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
error   15:47:02.516391-0600    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
error   15:47:02.520569-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.520868-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.523483-0600    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
error   15:47:02.523643-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.523905-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.524355-0600    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
error   15:47:02.524887-0600    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
error   15:47:02.525444-0600    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
error   15:47:02.525747-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.526027-0600    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
error   15:47:02.534198-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.534221-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.534250-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.538189-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.538403-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.540574-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.540812-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.542197-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.548639-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.548661-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.548690-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.552563-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.552773-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.554917-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.555298-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.557394-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.567913-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.567935-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.567965-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.575453-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.575737-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.578267-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.578540-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.580523-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:02.586743-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.586765-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.586791-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.624298-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.624639-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.624963-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:02.997972-0600    WindowServer    WSTransactionWindowMoveOnMatchingDisplayChangedSeed failed to move window cf (invalid seed 58)
error   15:47:03.164830-0600    com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent   Invalid display 0x042496d9
error   15:47:03.283626-0600    WindowServer    WSTransactionWindowMoveOnMatchingDisplayChangedSeed failed to move window 9767 (invalid seed 5e)
error   15:47:03.285980-0600    WindowServer    WSTransactionWindowMoveOnMatchingDisplayChangedSeed failed to move window 97f1 (invalid seed 5e)
error   15:47:03.287167-0600    WindowServer    WSTransactionWindowMoveOnMatchingDisplayChangedSeed failed to move window 97f1 (invalid seed 5e)
error   15:47:03.288081-0600    WindowServer    WSTransactionWindowMoveOnMatchingDisplayChangedSeed failed to move window 97f4 (invalid seed 5e)
error   15:47:03.288986-0600    WindowServer    WSTransactionWindowMoveOnMatchingDisplayChangedSeed failed to move window 97f4 (invalid seed 5e)
error   15:47:04.841315-0600    QuickLookUIService  suspending queue <private>
error   15:47:04.841396-0600    QuickLookUIService  requesting rendering of page 0 with size <private> flavor 0
error   15:47:04.841451-0600    QuickLookUIService  set current operation: <private> [_renderQueue operations]: <private>, _operations: <private>
error   15:47:04.841576-0600    QuickLookUIService  resuming queue <private>
error   15:47:04.841677-0600    QuickLookUIService  starting rendering of page 0 with size <private> flavor 0
error   15:47:04.854893-0600    QuickLookUIService  completion of operation <private>
error   15:47:04.855012-0600    QuickLookUIService  done with rendering operation: <private>
error   15:47:04.875308-0600    ReportCrash Invalid receipt [0 bytes]
error   15:47:04.964564-0600    Google Chrome Helper (Plugin)   CMIOHardware.cpp:333:CMIOObjectGetPropertyData the System is exiting
error   15:47:04.964695-0600    Google Chrome Helper (Plugin)   CMIO_DALA_System.cpp:264:GetPropertyData error 1970171760 (<private>) getting property selector (<private>) scope (<private>) element 0
error   15:47:05.116061-0600    ReportCrash Invalid receipt [0 bytes]
error   15:47:07.998378-0600    WindowServer    WSTransactionWindowMoveOnMatchingDisplayChangedSeed window cf has not moved from (1709.000000, 20.000000) after 5 seconds. It is likely misplaced.
error   15:47:08.284533-0600    WindowServer    WSTransactionWindowMoveOnMatchingDisplayChangedSeed window 9767 has not moved from (240.000000, 922.000000) after 5 seconds. It is likely misplaced.
error   15:47:08.289237-0600    WindowServer    WSTransactionWindowMoveOnMatchingDisplayChangedSeed window 97f4 has not moved from (-2000.000000, 3440.000000) after 5 seconds. It is likely misplaced.
error   15:47:08.289269-0600    WindowServer    WSTransactionWindowMoveOnMatchingDisplayChangedSeed window 97f4 has not moved from (-2000.000000, 3440.000000) after 5 seconds. It is likely misplaced.
error   15:47:09.870831-0600    apsd    <private>: Preferences may have changed, checking for any relevant changes
error   15:47:18.728362-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.728674-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.732253-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.733158-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.743578-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.743875-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.747220-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.748162-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.759378-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.759665-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.762991-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.763866-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.774291-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.774578-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.777892-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.778770-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.782418-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.782694-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.785906-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.786557-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.790343-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.790606-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.793725-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.794800-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.804258-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.804516-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.807606-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.808569-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.833149-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.833400-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.836266-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.837156-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.845256-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.845515-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.848746-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.849786-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:18.854291-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - ColorSyncUtilsUpdateDisplayProfiles: NULL device for (displayID = 0x003f0045, "Thunderbolt Display"): skipped
error   15:47:19.040582-0600    apsd    <private>: Preferences may have changed, checking for any relevant changes
error   15:47:20.165009-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.165533-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.172518-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.174618-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.193768-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.194411-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.201251-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.203582-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.213289-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.213807-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.219233-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.220824-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.239051-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.239625-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.244813-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.247175-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.248790-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:20.248828-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:20.248872-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:20.256664-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.256975-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.260945-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.262617-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.264053-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:20.264091-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:20.264132-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:20.270498-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.270809-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.275474-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.277427-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities from capabilities with no devices
error   15:47:20.278558-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:20.278578-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:20.278604-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:20.323561-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:20.324186-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:20.324580-0600    WindowServer    [ERROR] - Attempting to get capabilities when none exist
error   15:47:20.824429-0600    WindowServer    WSTransactionWindowMoveOnMatchingDisplayChangedSeed failed to move window cf (invalid seed 5f)
error   15:47:22.259316-0600    QuickLookUIService  suspending queue <private>
error   15:47:22.259440-0600    QuickLookUIService  requesting rendering of page 0 with size <private> flavor 0
error   15:47:22.259520-0600    QuickLookUIService  set current operation: <private> [_renderQueue operations]: <private>, _operations: <private>
error   15:47:22.259650-0600    QuickLookUIService  resuming queue <private>
error   15:47:22.259741-0600    QuickLookUIService  starting rendering of page 0 with size <private> flavor 0
error   15:47:22.275886-0600    QuickLookUIService  completion of operation <private>
error   15:47:22.276015-0600    QuickLookUIService  done with rendering operation: <private>
error   15:47:22.400162-0600    ReportCrash Invalid receipt [0 bytes]
error   15:47:22.400815-0600    ReportCrash Invalid receipt [0 bytes]
error   15:47:32.527517-0600    Music   RequireAction failure: ("!mRequireMetricsDict")
error   15:47:32.527543-0600    Music   Assertion failure: err == (-50)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I realize that it really could be the monitor here that is the issue (or something in an app I use), but I can't for the life of me find ANYONE with this issue on the Community at apple.com or elsewhere. Searches lead me down a rabbit hole of other issues and here I am. I'd like to not have to buy a new monitor, my TB display is an amazing monitor for my needs.

It sucks getting bad news, but it's your monitor.

Two different machines and two different Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2/1 adapters exhibit the same symptoms with the same monitor; you're down to only one remaining variable - the monitor.

You could potentially repair this monitor.  Without putting hands on, I would guess it to be either (ranked in order of likelihood)

- Power supply. The symptoms sound like it could be a bad capacitor in the power supply providing inconsistent power to any number of the power rails feeding the logic board. Too little or uneven power can send one of the chips on the logic board into a "panic" and cause it to turn off, reset, etc.
- Logic board.  This too could be a capacitor  or component on the logic board side of things that's causing a chip to malfunction.  Then again, it could be an IC (integrated circuit; aka "chip") itself that's failing.

Is it worth fixing?

From an economic stand point, not really.  You could spend several hundred dollars repairing to what amounts to a (at least) 4 year old display that's only capable of delivering QHD.  I'd put that money into a quality 4K display instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this with Thunderbolt-attached RAIDs. It happens after the computer sleeps; the RAIDs (I have two Areca RAIDs, daisy-chained) shut down and then restart. They then remain stable while the computer is asleep and then when I wake it up.

I was running an application in the Xcode debugger and noticed this in the console output:

> [default] enable_updates_common timed out waiting for updates to
> reenable

attributed to my app. After finding no such string in the code, I searched and ended up here. I have a late-2014 iMac running Big Sur.